# Cypress example for stubbing typing username and password into window.prompt

Tags: cypress

I am very new to Cypress and spend half days looking examples on how to send text in prompt.
I have tried the code below, but am getting an error.

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')   
cy.window().then((win) => {  
  cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('username', 'password') 
})
```

Requirements:

I need to enter username and password and click the window prompt submit button or close the window without entering username and password. Any ideas please?

Comment: Welcome to SO!
Please improve your question with information on what you have already researched, tried and how/where are you stuck! More (but not all) code and errors got would help!

Answer (score 1):

The stub must be set up before the code that uses `window.prompt`.

It's tricky with `window` methods because `window` is reset by the `cy.visit()`.

There's a hook `onBeforeLoad` provided to do this

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000', {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns('myUserName')  // no actual prompt occurs
  },
})

cy.get('.userName').invoke('text')  // if username is displayed on page, test it
  .should('eq', 'myUserName')
```

---

**Two prompts**

To stub username and password in the same test,

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000', {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    cy.stub(win, 'prompt').callsFake((message) => {
      if (message === 'User name:') return 'myUserName'
      if (message === 'Password:') return 'myPassword'
    })
  },
})
```

---

#### Are you really using `window.prompt`?

A `window.prompt` would look like this

[image]

But a React app probably has a popup window to login.

If so, do not use stubbing, use

```js
cy.get('selector-for-username').type('myUsername')
cy.get('selector-for-password').type('myPassword')
cy.get('selector-for-submit').click()
```

Comment: Hi user16695029, 

Thank you so much for your reply. We are making a call to 3rd party api endpoints where getting a default browser prompt to enter username and password.

We have tried this cy.visit('http://username:password@example.com') but getting error. Due to client restrictions, I cannot share the error message. Apologies

Comment: How Can I get the property for browser window and pass the username and password and click submit button? Can we close the window instead of sending password?

Comment: I'm very sorry, I'm not really understanding what the question is.

Comment: Step 1. Calling an api end point for some data.
Step 2. When Cypress is running and calling external api, browser prompt to enter username and password.
3. Question is how Can I reference that external pop window to enter username and password and then click on submit or Can I not enter any username and password and simply Can I close that window? Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: So, nothing to do with stubbing window prompts?

Comment: No. Not at the moment. Sorry. API end point require to authenticate to get the data. I am not sure how to bypass this by closing window or how to pass credentials to pass the test.

Comment: How about you change the question, and I will delete my answer?

Comment: Please do not delete your answer as it is very helpful for me and others.